# Why checkboxes dont change from checked to unchecked on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React App doesn't work like it should be. The problem is that the checkboxes dont change at all.
I managed to show the checked boxes (the ones with the property of completed=true) and debugging it seems that it works fine when I click but for some reason the box that needs to be changed automatically re-changes on its own.

Do you have any idea why ?

```
//APP.JS
import React from "react"

import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header"
import TodoItem from "./todoItem";
import todosData from "./todosData"


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        todos: todosData
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        const newArray = prevState.todos.map((elem) => {
          if(elem.id === id) {
            elem.completed = !(elem.completed)
          }
          return elem
        })
        return {
          todos: newArray
        }
      })
    }

    render() {
      const todosArray = this.state.todos.map(item => 
          <TodoItem
              key={item.id} 
              item={item}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />)

      return (
        <div className="App">
              <Header />
              <div className="container">
                  {todosArray}
              </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default App;


//TODOITEM.JS
import React from "react"

function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <div className="elem-container">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked={props.item.completed}
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <span className="span-container">{props.item.text}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem

//TODOSDATA.JS
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
        completed: false
    }
]

export default todosData
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change two things and it will work just fine
first:
inside todoItem.js

```
onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e,props.item.id)}
```

second:
inside the parent file

```
handleChange(event, id) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const newArray = prevState.todos.map((elem) => {
      if(elem.id === id) {
        elem.completed = event.target.checked
      }
      return elem
    })
    return {
      todos: newArray
    }
  })
}
```

now everything will work as you expected
have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert as I'm learning React myself but looking at the code handleChange(id) doesn't have an else state in its 'if' statement, have you tried adding?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @mouheb answer, you can simplify one more step. you don't need to `map` the all elements to update single item. you can change directly item (if it is mutable).

```
// todoItem.js
onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, props.item) }
```

```
// parent file

handleChange(event, prop) {
  prop.completed = event.target.
  this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos }) or this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos] })
}
```